# Default CSS styling to use with new projects

Tags: css

I have a set of default styles I use with new projects and want to know whether there are any issues or imperfections with them. Can anyone see anything that could be detrimental or bad in any way?

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5% /* makes 1rem 10px */
}
body {
    font-size: 1.6em; /* default font of 16px */
    font-family: 'Verdana', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.3;
    color: #373737;
}
/* fonts */
h1 { font-size: 3rem }
h2 { font-size: 2.4rem }
h3 { font-size: 2rem }
h4, li, label, input, textarea, select, p {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}
h5 { font-size: 1.6rem }
h6 { font-size: 1.4rem }
ol, ul { padding-left: 2em }
a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}
a:hover { color: pink }
a:focus { color: orange }
a:active { color: red }
a:visited { color: purple }
```

I'd be curious to know your thoughts or any feedback. Thank you.

Comment: This belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

It looks preety good to me, although I don't like using h5 and h6 tags to smaller texts. Tags "h" are heads and should always work as highlighted information.